# CAPTCHA control working in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, captcha

Can you please point me to an implementation of asp.net CAPTCHA control which work on AZURE?
(It should not employ sessions)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use Session data, then there are solutions out there, e.g. http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20040331.asp - or you could use a human-test instead of a captcha - e.g. asking what 6 times 9 is

However, it's probably best to instead use a third party solution such as http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully deployed the Google Recaptcha on Azure.
I used the NuGet recaptchaNet package, running under MVC 5.
My site is SSL, and there is bug in the NuGet package if you use SSL. Two occurrences of this:

https://api-verify.recaptcha.net/verify

need to be changed to this:

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify

or the verification of the Captcha fails on SSL Certificate error.